# How to adjust the initial step of fminunc?

Tags: matlab

I have two images that I need to match by transforming one to the other through translation and rotation. For this I have a function like this:

```
function [differences] = cost_function(transformation)

disp(transformation);

offset_x = transformation(1); % one of the images will be shifted by these many
offset_y = transformation(2); % pixels in either direction
angle    = transformation(3); % and rotated by this much

% snip:
%   * transform the second image
%   * otsu treshold both
%   * xor the results
%   * count pixels that xored
```

Then I try to find its minimum!

```
best_transform = fminunc(@cost_function, [0 0 0]);
```

However, the solver log shows a very big problem:

```
  1.0e-007 *
    0.1490         0         0
  1.0e-007 *
         0    0.1490         0
  1.0e-007 *
         0         0    0.1490
         0         0         1
    0.0000         0    1.0000
         0    0.0000    1.0000
         0         0    1.0000
         0         0    0.3333
    0.0000         0    0.3333
```

The solver tries to nudge ever so slightly in each dimension to find the best line to proceed in, but obviously shifting an image by 0.1490 pixels really doesn't do much, while shifting it by 0.1490 radians naturally does. I don't know, however, where 0.1490 actually came from.

[The documentation](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/toolbox/optim/ug/fminunc.html#f854831) doesn't seem to give advice here. How can I increase the initial step of the solver?

Answer (score 2):

`fminunc` is designed to find a minimum of a continuous function, which, as you pointed out, is not your case since changing the number of pixels you shift your image by an infinitesimal amount results in no outcome.

You can solve this problem by properly scaling your objective function in a way that *fools* `fminunc` into believing your function is indeed continuous. To accomplish that, simply multiply your offset parameters by a reasonably large scalar such as:

```
offset_x = transformation(1)*1000; 
offset_y = transformation(2)*1000; 
angle    = transformation(3);
```

and divide your final solution by the same set of scalars to get the number of pixels shifted.

In general, proper scaling of variables in nonlinear optimization problems is crucial even if your problem does not suffer from discontinuity issues.

Answer (score 0):

I currently have this kludge:

```
best_score_so_far = 9999999999;
best_so_far = [0 0 0];
optimset('display', 'off', 'MaxIter', 100);
for dist = 1:1:10
    for angle = 0:2*pi/4/dist:2*pi
        x = cos(angle)*dist;
        y = sin(angle)*dist;
        disp([dist angle x y]); %heh
        [best, cost] = fminunc(@(angle)cost_function([x,y,angle]), 0);
        if(cost < best_score_so_far)
            best_score_so_far = cost;
            best_so_far = best;
        end
    end
end
```

...but it's ugly, super slow, and, well, a kludge.